# Error code for an invalid POST parameter

Tags: rfc2616

What's the proper error code to return when a POST
request has an invalid parameter? Say: a form takes data
for an event, but the date provided is in the past; or a
form takes data for a user registration, but the name provided
is a number or any invalid person name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [REST response code for invalid data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6123425/rest-response-code-for-invalid-data)

Answer (score 7):

> 11.2. 422 Unprocessable Entity
>
> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

(From [RFC 4918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2))

Answer (score 0):

i would personally opt for: 400 Bad Request

the error should be in the 4xx range which represents client errors, because it is the responsibility of the client to transmit valid data.

anyway, you can have a look at a [list of standard HTTP response codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) and chose one that seems to fit your need.

Comment: Isn't 400 reserved for bad syntax? An invalid parameter may be invalid but syntactically correct.

Comment: the rfc says: "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax", but sending a number instead of a date is a bad syntax, although the client can send the request. specifically, the query parameters can be considered as a part of the request, and can thus trigger some errors. error "409 Conflict" is such a good example.

Comment: Sending a number instead of a date is bad syntax, but sending an invalid date in the place of a date is not. What should I use then?

Comment: We've tried to clarify this in httpbis, see https://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/draft-ietf-httpbis/latest/p2-semantics.html#status.400