# Cannot include relational data with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, include, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to include relational data with my Company model. When I'm not using `Include`, I get my answer but when I'm not including I get `Could not get any response` in Postman.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string with, string orderBy)
{
   CustContext context = new CustContext();

   var companies = context.Companies.Include(c => c.Stores).ToListAsync();

   return Ok(companies);
}
```

I want to return the answer in `json` format, which it handles by it self when not including.

Someone having a clue of what's not going well?

EDIT

When I'm debugging I see that `companies` is set properly together with `Stores`. There must be something wrong when returning the result.

Comment: Why not to return `Task<JsonResult>`?

Comment: I like using the `Ok()` function. Is there a nice way of setting the status code when returning `Task<JsonResult>`?

Comment: I believe that the status code is set properly when the method reurns, isn't it?

Comment: No sometimes you'd like a BadRequest or NotAuthorized etc. Default is 200 OK

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183004/return-mvc-jsonresult-plus-set-response-statuscode) question, maybe it suits for you problem.

Comment: Yeah, although its a bit off the subject. There's no problem regarding the status code - I'm not getting any answer at all, with or without returning as a JsonResult :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Apparently we need to explicit tell the framework not to keep including (until infinity and beyond). So, this has to be added in `startup.cs`

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```