# API call with correct access token in header gives me a 401 unauthorized

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I'm requesting a token against an identity server app, that we used on a previous project, for the current project. On my local machine, so localhost level.

The token request works:

```
IdentityServer3.Core.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGeneratorCreating token response
IdentityServer3.Core.ResponseHandling.TokenResponseGeneratorProcessing token request
Identity.Api.Monitoring.IdentityEventServiceInformation - 2020 - Refresh token issued -  - IdentityServer3.Core.Events.RefreshTokenDetails
Identity.Api.Monitoring.IdentityEventServiceInformation - 2000 - Access token issued -  - IdentityServer3.Core.Events.AccessTokenIssuedDetails
Identity.Api.Monitoring.IdentityEventServiceSuccess - 3000 - Endpoint success -  - IdentityServer3.Core.Events.EndpointDetail
IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.TokenEndpointControllerEnd token request
IdentityServer3.Core.Results.TokenResultReturning token response.
```

I get this response:

```
{
    "access_token": "myaccesstoken",
    "expires_in": 86400,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "refresh_token": "myrefreshtoken"
}
```

Now if I use that token on my request, I get a `401 unauthorized` response:

[image]

> At face value I'd expect this call to work, as I'm passing a correct
>   token. So, what can I do to figure out why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authorization header should have **Bearer** instead of **BASIC**

```
Authorization: Bearer SomeTokenHere
```

Comment: Oh, that simple, no idea how that got there. An oversight :).

Comment: As an aside, a 400 Bad Request response would seem more logical than the 401 I got. Receiving that 401 made me overthink the issue as I had no direction to look at.

Comment: I believe 400 is returned as it won't consider the Basic Auth header as a proper formatted request.. Discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576898/what-is-the-most-appropriate-http-status-code-to-return-if-a-required-header-is