# What's the correct HttpStatusCode to return for a required parameter that's missing?

Tags: http-status-codes, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a Web API method to check if a name is unique of that type and need to make sure the name parameter is given. What's the correct status code to return?

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetIsNameUnique(string name)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(layoutName))
  {
      throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage { 
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.{What Goes Here?},
         Content = new StringContent("The name is required.")
      });
  }
  // more code here to check....
}
```

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050518/what-http-status-response-code-should-i-use-if-the-request-is-missing-a-required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

400, or if the name parameter is part of the URI then you could return 404.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 400 seems to be the best answer, rather than the 412, I mentioned below.

After looking at the link provided by codebox in the comment of this question, I'm going to go with 412, PreconditionFailed. From the System.Net.HttpStatusCode file

```
// Summary:
//     Equivalent to HTTP status 412. System.Net.HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed
//     indicates that a condition set for this request failed, and the request cannot
//     be carried out. Conditions are set with conditional request headers like
//     If-Match, If-None-Match, or If-Unmodified-Since.
```

Comment: There are no conditional request headers involved here.

Comment: @CBroe Do you think a straight 400 would be better then?

Comment: Seems to be the lowest common denominator. Mostly all other 4xx status codes that could be applicable refer to specific header fields for expectations not met etc. I think a 400 together with an error message that explains the specific reason, maybe even some kind of exception format with an error code, might be best.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It looks like people are voting to close this question as a duplicate, so we'll see how long it lasts.