# Response validation failed Swagger

Tags: node.js, swagger

I'm defining an API using swagger. I have a certain operation that should return something like this.

```
{"isDeviceLoaded":true,"loadedDeviceProperties":  {"deviceType":"Gadget","deviceProp1":0,"deviceLoadedConfigurations":[{"width":0,"length":0,"distanceToTopLeft":0}]}}
```

The problem is when the "isDeviceLoaded:false" I don't want to return all the properties, so in this case the return value should be only.

```
{"isDeviceLoaded":false}
```

I defined my model as below following this [Swagger - Specify Optional Object Property or Multiple Responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27844127/swagger-specify-optional-object-property-or-multiple-responses)

```
DeviceMediaStatus: 
type: "object"
required: ["isDeviceLoaded"]
properties: 
  isDeviceLoaded: 
    type: "boolean"
  loadedDeviceProperties: 
    type: "object"
    $ref: "#/definitions/LoadedDeviceProperties"
```

but when in my code I try to return only the isDeviceLoaded property I get a response validation failed. This is what I'm doing in my JS and "object" has the data.

```
  if(object.LoadedDeviceStatus.isDeviceLoaded){
      response = object.LoadedDeviceStatus;
      res.status(200).send(response);
  }else{
      response = object.LoadedDeviceStatus.isDeviceLoaded;
      res.status(200).send(response);
  }
```

Comment: Who's throwing the response validation error? What is res?

Comment: Can you please post the error you are getting on the response?  Also can you post more of your JS code?  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I solved it. The problem was with an npm package that was missing. Thank you very much!