# What should be the http error code for passing blank value in a mandatory parameter which should not be blank?

Tags: api, rest, error-code

for example:

post method:

```
{
  name = "",
  id = 1,
  class = 4
}
```

name should not be a blank parameter but i am still sending it this way in a post/put request call. what should be the output error code for such data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many use 400 Bad Request. This [used to indicate bad syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.1), but the [latest HTTP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1) makes it more expansive.

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or
> will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be
> a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request
> message framing, or deceptive request routing).

I prefer the more specific [422 Unprocessable Entity](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4918#section-11.2). This indicates that the syntax was fine, but the semantics were wrong.

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server
> understands the content type of the request entity (hence a
> 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the
> syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request)
> status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained
> instructions.  For example, this error condition may occur if an XML
> request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but
> semantically erroneous, XML instructions.

Technically 422 is from WebDAV, not HTTP, but it doesn't matter. Many APIs use 422.

Either is acceptable.

See also [What HTTP status response code should I use if the request is missing a required parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050518/what-http-status-response-code-should-i-use-if-the-request-is-missing-a-required).